# How do I slice an array in KRL

Tags: arrays, slice, krl

I have a bunch of HTML fragments in an array (thank you query()) but I only want to use the first five. I'm using `foreach` to inject the fragments into a page.

If my array was [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] I would want just [0,1,2,3,4]. In Python I would use A[:5].

How can I select the first few elements of an array and ignore the rest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pick() for this, but it only appears to work correctly if the items in your array are objects, not numbers or strings:

```
    a = [{'n':"a"},{'n':"b"},{'n':"c"},{'n':"d"}];
    b = a.pick("$[2:]");
```

in the above example, `b == [{'n' :'c'}, {'n' :'d'}]`

I've filed a bug about the number and string failures.

It would also be possible to create a recursive function that returned the proper slice of the array, but it does sound a bit painful.

Comment: get_five = function(a) {a.pick("$[5:]")} //given the bug fix

Comment: foreach my_dataset[:5] setting (n) // provide slice to foreach

Comment: foreach my_dataset.pick("$[:5]") setting (n) //correct way to foreach the slice.